# display non-printable chars in winforms textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, character

I am trying to display non-printable characters (space, line break) in a winforms multiline textbox, a feature found in most text processing tools.

I am doing this by

```
textbox.Text.Replace(' ','·').Replace(Environment.NewLine, "¶" + Environment.NewLine);
```

This works fine so far, but because of the missing spaces automatic word wrap is not working any more. 
So I try to measure the length of each line to add the word wrap manually, but I am not getting the desired results:

```
private int GetTextWidth(TextBox tb)
{
    using (var g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(tb.Text, tb.Font);
        int width = (int)(size.Width + 0.5);
        return width;
    }
}
```

GetTextWidth returns different results for different characters. When I type a line of "l"s, then GetTextWidth == textbox.Width will be reached after ~80%, with "M"s a linebreak occurs even before GetTextWidth == textbox.Width.

Using a monospace font is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [`Zero width space`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space)

```
textbox.Text.Replace(" ","·\u200B")
```

It should still allow line breaks but will not look like anything. Backspaces/deletes will appear to behave oddly so you'll probably need to acknowledge you're about to delete a `.` representing a zero width space (or vice versa) and know to delete both characters with a single key press.

Answer (score 0):

The `Graphics.MeasureString()` method is inaccurate by design. For alternatives, see the Remarks sections on the [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).